# ExtJS 4.1 - How to override all fields

Tags: javascript, extjs4, overriding, extjs4.1

I want to apply a plugin to **all fields**(*numberfield, textfield, datefield, etc.*) in the library **ExtJS 4.1**.
Is there anyone who knows how can I do this?

As I know, all fields are extended from **BaseField**. So I tried this; but it didn't work at all. I'll be happy if someone can guide me.

Thanks in advance.

```
Ext.form.BaseField.override({
     plugins    : [ 'clearbutton' ]
});
```

Comment: This is an invalid question since it doesn't make sense to override all fields with the clearbutton extension.  Certain form fields in Extjs 4.1 are not compatible with clearbutton.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this syntax will work better?

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.field.Base, {
   plugins    : [ 'clearbutton' ]
});
```

Comment: unfortunately getting this error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

Comment: I tried it out and got the same error.  The clear button does not work on textareas apparently.  There is no solution to your problem as it is stated.  You will have to override specifically the fields that are compatible with clearbutton.

Comment: Oops, my last statement is incorrect, after more investigating, it is actually Ext.form.field.Display causing the issue in my case because there is no actual <input> element rendered for that field.  This makes sense because you shouldn't allow a user to clear a field that he/she can't enter data into.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override initComponent method :

```
Ext.form.BaseField.override({
 initComponent : function(){
   var me = this;
   me.plugins = Ext.Array.merge(me.plugins || [],  [ 'clearbutton' ]);
   me.callParent();
 }
});
```